# How to integrate Laravel with Vue.js in a Restful API application?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.4

Imagine a resource `Post` that you can perform CRUD on using a Restful API:

```
// in routes/api.php ...

GET     /api/v1/posts           API\V1\PostController@index
POST    /api/v1/posts           API\V1\PostController@store
GET     /api/v1/posts/{post}    API\V1\PostController@show
PATCH   /api/v1/posts/{post}    API\V1\PostController@update
// etc.
```

As you can see, each endpoint is handled by a controller action in `Controllers\API\PostController`, such as `index`, `store`, `show`, `update`, etc., as per Laravel conventions. Now, there's also a front-end dedicated controller, `Controllers\PostController` whose only responsibility is respond to one route `/posts` (in `routes/web.php`) and render a view:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('posts.index');
}
```

In turn, this `index.blade.php` has many Vue components, one that GETs and lists all `Post`s from the API using Axios, one that POSTs and creates a new `Post` object, and others to update, delete, etc. Now, the problem is, **how do I organize and name these components?** Here's my shot:

- Under `assets/js/components`, I created a `posts` folder, and added `index.js`, `show.js`, `create.js`, `update.js`, etc., mimicking the Blade views that I would have otherwise created in a traditional Laravel app;
- Each file follows a standard...

  ```
  module.exports = {
      data() {
          return { /* data here */ };
      },
      created() {
          /* processing here */
      }
  }
  ```
- ...and is registered in `assets/js/app.js` following a `<resource_name-action>` pattern:

  ```
  Vue.component('post-index', require('./components/posts/index.js'));
  ```
- Lastly, components are used in `index.blade.php` as inline templates:

  ```
  <post-index inline-template>
      <!-- HTML markup here -->
  </post-index>
  ```

#### Questions

1. Would this structure comply with recommended practices in Vue / Laravel?
2. Is it salable enough? Are component / file names semantic and/or standard?
3. Are there aspects that I neglected? Is it productive to have your views communicate with your API and DB in a single app? Or should they be split into two apps, one for front-end, another for back-end?